# scanEachPoll in FileReadingMessageSource in Spring Integration Listener

Tags: java, duplicates, queue, spring-integration, listener

In Spring Integration Listener, there is a class file call `FileReadingMessageSource`, there is a boolean variable that allow coder to modified on it by its method `setScanEachPoll(boolean scanEachPoll)`.

I manage to do it, and the listener will scan the directory every cycle. However, I found something wrong, which is the `toBeReceived` queue will keep append file inside everytime it scan the directory.

For example, file a, b, c, d, e.

1st cycle, scan, queue will have a,b,c,d,e --> process a, queue left b,c,d,e

2nd cycle, scan, queue will have b,c,d,e,b,c,d,e --> process b, queue left c,d,e,b,c,d,e
It will have duplicate file name inside the queue.

Here is paste the `scanInputDirectory()` method from the `FileReadingMessageSource` class.

```
private void scanInputDirectory() {
    List<File> filteredFiles = scanner.listFiles(directory);
    Set<File> freshFiles = new LinkedHashSet<File>(filteredFiles);
    if (!freshFiles.isEmpty()) {
        toBeReceived.addAll(freshFiles);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Added to queue: " + freshFiles);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: Doesn’t `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` help you?

Comment: @ArtemBilan that won't help; we'll end up with an OOM; the queue should be cleared (or not even used - or we should only add the first file instead of `this.toBeReceived.addAll(freshFiles);`).

Comment: Or anything I can do to make the scanner to scan only 1 file and only put 1 file in the queue? instead of whole file in directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to handle this problem by creating my own Scanner.

which is

```
<bean id="myDirectoryScanner" class="bp.main.myDirectoryScanner" ></bean>
```

My scanner only return the first item:

```
protected File[] listEligibleFiles(File directory)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {

        File[] rootFiles = directory.listFiles();
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(rootFiles.length);
        if ( rootFiles != null ) {
            files.add(rootFiles[0]);
        }
        return files.toArray(new File[files.size()]);
    }
```

Comment: Isn’t that what is done by the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/HeadDirectoryScanner.java? On the other hand I would like to see some test-case to play locally, because I still believe that `AcceptOnceFileListFlter` injected to the `DefaultDirectoryScanner` does its trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I still believe that `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` won't let the same files to be pulled from the target directory: see `DefaultDirectoryScanner.listFiles()` and how it uses `this.filter`.

OTOH the OOM problem can be fixed via `internalQueueCapacity` ctor arg of the `FileReadingMessageSource`:

```
/**
 * Creates a FileReadingMessageSource with a bounded queue of the given
 * capacity. This can be used to reduce the memory footprint of this
 * component when reading from a large directory.
 *
 * @param internalQueueCapacity
 *            the size of the queue used to cache files to be received
 *            internally. This queue can be made larger to optimize the
 *            directory scanning. With scanEachPoll set to false and the
 *            queue to a large size, it will be filled once and then
 *            completely emptied before a new directory listing is done.
 *            This is particularly useful to reduce scans of large numbers
 *            of files in a directory.
 */
public FileReadingMessageSource(int internalQueueCapacity) {
    this(null);
    Assert.isTrue(internalQueueCapacity > 0,
            "Cannot create a queue with non positive capacity");
    this.scanner = new HeadDirectoryScanner(internalQueueCapacity);
}
```

Then see JavaDocs of that class:

```
 * A custom scanner that only returns the first <code>maxNumberOfFiles</code>
 * elements from a directory listing. This is useful to limit the number of File
 * objects in memory and therefore mutually exclusive with {@code AcceptOnceFileListFilter}.
 * It should not be used in conjunction with an {@code AcceptOnceFileListFilter}.
```

However it can't be used with the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` and the processed files have to be deleted in the end to avoid them on the next poll.

Also see more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-reading).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. But actually my problem is only queue there, yes, correct, the scanner will only pull the unique files from the directory, but  it will still add into the `toBeReceived` Queue. Then inside this queue will have duplicate.